# swagger отправить ассоциативный массив

Tags: php, node.js, swagger

Как через swagger отправить данные form-data

```
currency[0][currency_id] = 5
currency[0][is_default] = true

currency[1][currency_id] = 1
currency[1][is_default] = false

currency[2][currency_id] = 3
currency[2][is_default] = false
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убил на это часа 3, так ничего не получилось....

Answer (score 0):

Swagger это прослойка, middlware, спецификация между вами и непосредственно route handler. Данные следует отправлять как указано в спецификации иначе эта прослойка не пропустит ваш запрос до назначения.

Comment: Это мой сваггер, у меня апи принимает в том формате в котором я указал

Comment: Тогда скиньте спецификацию. Форматы запросов и прочих. Как вам помочь если не хватает информации?